# Насколько возможно сочетание?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, терминология

"Речевой способ" в значении "манера выражения мысли, те или иные конструкции фраз", например:

> С этими речевыми способами сообразуется мышление.

Answer (score 1):

Такое сочетание встречается только в узкоспециальных контекстах, например: *речевой способ* оповещения (об опасности), *речевой способ* общения "человек-машина" - о способах достижения чего-либо посредством речи.

В вашем случае для выражения предлагаемого смысла правильнее говорить о *риторических приёмах*.